# Read from Sqlite3 output list

Tags: python, sqlite

My problem is the following:

I have a database which contains cars.

If I search for a car by sqlite3 in python this works fine.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM autos WHERE Id = (?)",(deck1[1]))
auto1 = cursor.fetchall()
print(auto1[])
```

My output then looks like this:

[(1, 'bmw_z4', 240, 268, 1563, 7, 42500, 'BMW Z4')]

How do I read from this?

As an example in this case I just want to print the model name "BMW Z4".
But for some reason I just cant handle this output as a list. I tryed "print(output[1])" but this gives the error "list index out of range".

Anyone who knows how to fix it?

Comment: `[(1, 'bmw_z4', 240, 268, 1563, 7, 42500, 'BMW Z4')] ` is a list of tuples. it means that `auto1[0][1]` will return 'bmw_z4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is a list of tuples. In this case, we have just one tuple inside our list. So, to access the information you want, first we need to index the tuple and, after that, the element of the tuple. To get the 'BMW Z4' information, we can use the code below:

```
print(output[0][7])
```

We are getting the tuple in the position 0 of the list and the element in the position 7 of the tupĺe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. this anwers fixes all issues for my game mechanic!!!